# Creating a dummy variable based on a string pattern in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have the following dataset. None is defined as a python missing value. The type is object (from dt.types)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['triparty'])
df["triparty"] = ["AB65", "None", "GDW322", "DASED", "None"]
```

I want to create a dummy that takes the value 1 when triparty is None and 0 otherwise. I tried out several variations of

```
df["triparty"]=[0 if df["triparty"] == np.NaN else 1 for x in df["triparty"]]

df["triparty"]=[0 if df["triparty"] == "None" else 1 for x in df["triparty"]]
```

but it does not seem to work. I get the error message ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `np.where`

```
df["dummy"] = np.where(df["triparty"] == "None", 0, 1)
print(df)
```

Or create column of `bool` as `int` type.

```
df["dummy"] = (df["triparty"] != "None").astype(int)
# or
df["dummy"] = (~(df["triparty"] == "None")).astype(int)
```

Output

```
  triparty  dummy
0     AB65      1
1     None      0
2   GDW322      1
3    DASED      1
4     None      0
```